# java Long datatype comparison

Tags: java, comparison

Why does the code below return **false** for **long3 == long2** comparison even though it's literal.

```
public class Strings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long long1 = 256L + 256L;
        Long long2 = 512L;
        Long long3 = 512L;
        System.out.println(long3 == long2);
        System.out.println(long1.equals(long2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`Long` is an object, not a primitive. By using `==` you're comparing the *reference values*.

You need to do:

```
if(str.equals(str2))
```

As you do in your second comparison.

**Edit:** I get it ... you are thinking that other objects act like `String` literals. They don't*. And even then, you never want to use `==` with `String` literals either.

(*Autobox types do implement the flyweight pattern, but only for values -128 -> 127. If you made your `Long` equal to `50` you would indeed have two references to the same flyweight object. And again, *never use ==* to compare them. )

**Edit to add:** This is specifically stated in the Java Language Specification, [Section 5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7):

> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, or a char in the range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127 (inclusive), then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.

Note that `long` is **not** specifically mentioned but the current Oracle and OpenJDK implementations do so (1.6 and 1.7), which is yet another reason to **never** use `==`

```
Long l = 5L;
Long l2 = 5L;
System.out.println(l == l2);
l = 5000L;
l2 = 5000L;
System.out.println(l == l2);
```

Outputs:

> true
>   false

Comment: Hi Brian! Thanks for the answer, but can you tell me where can I find this explanation about this range (-128 -> 127)?

Comment: @RenatoLochetti It's covered in the [Java Language Spec (JLS) section 5.1.7 - last paragraph](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7). It's an implementation of the [Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)

Comment: @RenatoLochetti Edited question to expand on subject.

Answer (score 3):

You could also get the primitive value out of the Long object using:

```
str.longValue()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do

```
      str3==str2
```

do like this..

```
     str3.longValue()==str2.longValue()
```

This serves your purpose and much faster because you are comparing two primitive type values not objects.

Answer (score 1):

Here Long is a Wrapper class so the below line will compare the reference not the content.

`long3 == long2`

its always better to compare with ** .longValue() ** like below

`long3.longValue() == long2.longValue()`

If we use in-build equal() method that also will do the same thing with null check.

`long3.equals(long2)`

Below is the internal implementation of **equals()** in java

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Long) {
        return value == ((Long)obj).longValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```