# How to compare two long value at runtime in java

Tags: java, if-statement, runtime, long-integer

How to compare two long value at runtime. When I got the value of both of long type variable at runtime which same so it should be print else part but the both value is different from each other so it should be print if part.

```
Long dbData = 54188439.... // Got the value at run time
Long spreadSheet = 54188439.....//Got the value at run time

if(dbData != spreadSheet)
{
Log.i("","Please update your contact");
}
else
{
Log.i("","Not required");
}
```

Here I always got `if` part whatever be the condition. Please help me out.

Comment: You're comparing two different objects, whose contents just happen to be the same number

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20542511/1638708) - you're comparing Objects, not primitive `long` values

Comment: Nope I got the value of both variable at runtime. The value of both variable will anything. @MadProgrammer

Comment: @abc But `Long` is a `Object`, not a primitive ...

Answer (score 1):

Make use of **equals operator**

changed the statement from

```
if(dbData != spreadSheet)
```

to

```
  if(!dbData.equals(spreadSheet))
```

**When Same**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long dbData = new Long(54188439);
        Long spreadSheet = new Long(54188439);

        if (!dbData.equals(spreadSheet)) {
            System.out.println("Please update your contact");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not required");
        }
    }
```

**Output**

Not required

**When Different**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Long dbData = new Long(54188439);
    Long spreadSheet = new Long(541878439);

        if (!dbData.equals(spreadSheet)) {
            System.out.println("Please update your contact");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not required");
        }
    }
```

**output**

Please update your contact

Comment: In this condition, It also shows false condition @ankur-singhal

Comment: @abc What do you mean by false condition? What it is printing?

Comment: @abc i have edited the answer, see the output

Comment: how I added `L` at runtime. In my condition it always showing 'Please update your contact' @ankur-singhal

Comment: @abc `L` is something required when declaring.

Comment: @abc can you show us how you are getting values at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it won't work is because you are comparing the objects, not the values. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/8968390/4890300 for a great answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Bruce actually it does answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(dbData.longValue() != spreadSheet.longValue())
```

Edit your condition as above. It will compare 2 long values. Your exiting condition compare 2 object references.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should compare two instances of Long-class only with it's equals method, because == operators check the addresses, not the values.

```
if(!dbData.equals(spreadSheet)) 
{
  Log.i("","Please update your contact");
}
else
{
  Log.i("","Not required");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Long.compare(long x, long y)`

```
if (Long.compare(val1, val2) == 0) {
   // values are equal
} else {
   // values are not equal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `dbData` and `spreadSheet` are instances of the `Long` **class**, not `long` primitives. You have to compare theme either using the `equals()` method, or compare their `longValue()`s. I.e.

```
if (!dbData.equals(spreadSheet)) { 
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```

or

```
if (dbData.longValue() != spreadSheet.longValue()) { 
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
    Long dbData = 54188439L;// Got the value at run time
    Long spreadSheet = 54188439L;//Got the value at run time

    if (!dbData.equals(spreadSheet)) {


    }
```